# Modern Toolkit- Grid with Multiselection: How to make multiple checkboxes ticked on grid row selection.?

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs6-modern

In modern multiselection grid, Multiple checkboxes getting ticked only when i click on checkbox. But i want multiple checkboxes to be ticked on grid row selection. Can anyone please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following sample the selection is produced by tapping on row:

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Grid', {
    title: 'Streaming Service Providers',
    columns: [{
        text: "Brand",
        dataIndex: "brand",
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: "Headquarters",
        dataIndex: "headquarters",
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: "Trial",
        dataIndex: "trial",
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: "Price",
        flex: 1,
        dataIndex: 'price'
    }],
    store: {
        fields: ['brand', 'headquarters', 'trial', 'price'],
        data: [{
            brand: 'Netflix',
            headquarters: 'California',
            trial: '1 Month',
            price: '$7.99'
        }, {
            brand: 'YouTube',
            headquarters: 'California',
            trial: '1 Month',
            price: '$9.99'
        }, {
            brand: 'Amazon Prime',
            headquarters: 'Seattle, Washington',
            trial: '1 Month',
            price: '$8.25'
        }],
        storeId: 'serviceStore'
    },
    height: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    // Row checkbox selection model config
    selectable: {
        columns: false,
        mode: 'multi',
        checkbox: true,
        cells: false,
        rows: true,
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Arthur, I tried this code in fiddle. It's unchecking previously selected row, when i click on next row. I want both the rows to remain checked.

Comment: Have you tried to click with Ctrl on windows and Command on MacOS buttons? So called Ctrl-click..

Comment: Ctrl+click works well. Rows get selected. But my client wants it on row selection, not with ctrl+click. Let me know if it's possible. Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: And how will your client unselect the selected rows?

Comment: By clicking on the selected row again. This was possible with classic toolkit. But now trying to achieve this is modern toolkit.

Comment: It is still possible with classic toolkit. Unfortunately you will have to override the private 'onNavigate' method of the 'Ext.grid.selection.Model' class to achieve this behaviour. As you can see from source code of the selection model: if (sel && (mode !== 'multi' || !ctrlKey) && !isSpace) {
                    sel.clear(true);
                }